# the uimageview not refresh me from a url

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I need help, I have an application that collects my profile picture facebook, the problem is that if I change this profile picture on facebook and then go to my application, I still shows the old image, but the service returns me good url with the updated image, which can be happening?

```
if ([session sessionType] == MASTFacebook) {
         NSLog (@ "fbPictureURL:% @", [(MAFacebookSession *) session fbPictureURL]);

         [self.userImgView setImageWithURL [(MAFacebookSession *) session fbPictureURL]];

     }
```

[image]

Comment: Are you caching images ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are caching image, try to use `NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:-1];` and use method like `setImageWithURLRequest` to set your UIImageView.

In your case, the code should be like followings if you are using `UIImageView+AFNetworking`

```
if ([session sessionType] == MASTFacebook) {
    NSLog (@ "fbPictureURL:% @", [(MAFacebookSession *) session fbPictureURL]);
    NSURL *url = [(MAFacebookSession *) session fbPictureURL];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:-1]; 

    // if you are using UIImageView+AFNetworking. the method is as follows
    [self.userImgView setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:nil success:nil failure:nil]]; 

}
```

Comment: I do not reconoze the method setImageWithURLRequest

Comment: @user2652032 this is just a method works like this.why UIImageView category are you using?

Comment: @user2652032 you can also dig into your `setImageWithURL:` method to find one method looks like `setImageWithURLRequest`, which uses request as parameter.

Comment: sorry I'm not an expert on this, one does not know what you mean what kind of UIImageView'm using, I'm programming for ios 7 and tells me that this method not reconoze, I can do? no other way, or cleaning the cache?

Comment: @user2652032 `setImageWithURL:` is not standard UIImageView method from Apple, it should be from one 3rd party UIImageView Category.

Comment: Is there a UIImageView+AFNetworking.h file or something alike in your #import section?

Comment: does not exist, I used this and it seems to work, right?

  [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [(MAFacebookSession *) session fbPictureURL]] queue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler: ^ (NSURLResponse * response, NSData * data, NSError * error) {
             _userImgView.image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];
         }];

Comment: @user2652032 you'd better to add `cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData` part when you init the Request. then it will avoid caching your image when loading

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `setImageWithURL` so it will cache your image automatically by url , so you should also update image url after update image.

Comment: But i have the same url for different pictures, each call to the same url should provide new image. how can i clear the cache using -setImageWithURLRequest method?

Answer (score 0):

best way will be once you get the image url from Facebook convert it into UIImage and save it. depending on your requirement(app delegate , UserDefaults). Then assign it to ImageView. So that you can use image in any view controller as the your profile pic is already convert into Image it will not take time to convert(not caching but works as cache). when ever you login you can get the updated profile pic.
ex:

```
    NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

  [defaults setObject:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your image url" forKey:@"profileImage"];
```

Here you can saving Data (In UserDefaults we can not save image so we save data).

UIImageView *view =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithData:[defaults objectForKey:@"profileImage"]];